# mysql join select lowest price set flag

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two table join where one table holds product data and the other pricing data including multiple discount pricing. Not every product has multiple entries in the pricing table, as some products only have a single unit price.
What I'm trying to figure out is in my select how to set a flag that lets me know if a product has multiple pricing available.

The code I have now (see below) returns the products and finds the lowest price for each product. However like I said not all products have a "lowest price". I'm trying to determine if the price coming with the product is a single unit price or a lowest price.

```
SELECT products.*
     , products_pricing.* 
  FROM products
  LEFT 
  JOIN products_pricing 
    ON products.product_id = products_pricing.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN products_pricing AS filter 
    ON products_pricing.product_id = filter.product_id 
   AND products_pricing.qty_price > filter.qty_price 
 WHERE filter.product_id IS NULL 
   AND products.product_active > 0 
 ORDER 
    BY products.product_id DESC
```

Comment: (I am not familiar with MySQL) but could you subquery the products? Perhaps something like this, where you join to a subquery, or save this as a 'view' which you join?

    SELECT 
 MIN(PRICE),
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SINGLE_PRICE
    FROM PRODUCTS
    GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID

Comment: What would the desired result look like? Better yet, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I gather that every product has at least one price in `products_pricing`, so no need for an outer join.

Rather than using the anti join pattern, I would simply join with the aggregated product. Use a comparision of min/max or a count to get to your flag then.

```
select 
  p.*,
  pp.*,
  case when ppm.min_qty_price = ppm.max_qty_price then 'single' else 'multi' end as flag
from products p
join products_pricing pp on pp.product_id = p.product_id 
join 
(
  select product_id, min(qty_price) as min_qty_price, max(qty_price) as max_qty_price
  from products_pricing
  group by product_id
) ppm on ppm.product_id = pp.product_id
      and ppm.min_qty_price = pp.qty_price
where p.product_active > 0 
order by p.product_id desc;
```

Comment: New here and not sure if it's ok to say thanks so at the risk of being SO-politically incorrect... Thanks! This did just what I needed and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you dpn't need  all the column from the two tables but only the relevant columns

```
  SELECT products.product_id, count(*) as num_of_price
     , case when count(*) > 1 then 'MULTI PRICE' ELSE 'SINGLE PRICE' as flag_price
  FROM products
  LEFT 
  JOIN products_pricing 
    ON products.product_id = products_pricing.product_id 
 WHERE products.product_active > 0 
   GROUP BY products.product_id
 ORDER 
    BY products.product_id DESC
```

while if you need all the columns  you can join this result

```
SELECT products.*
     , products_pricing.*
     , t.*
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN products_pricing  ON products.product_id = products_pricing.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT products.product_id, count(*) as num_of_price
         , case when count(*) > 1 then 'MULTI PRICE' ELSE 'SINGLE PRICE' as flag_price
      FROM products
      LEFT 
      JOIN products_pricing 
        ON products.product_id = products_pricing.product_id 
     WHERE products.product_active > 0 
       GROUP BY products.product_id
    ) T ON products.product_id = T.product_id
ORDER 
    BY products.product_id DESC
```